# WiX Installer - overwrite ODBC entry?

Tags: wix

I am using wix to create an msi to install an ODBC driver. I can't find in the documentation how to set it to overwrite the ODBC keys. I'd like users to be able to retain multiple versions of my driver, but upon installing a new version I want to override the driver and setup links to the new version.

```
       <Component Guid="{fc5fc424-c8d0-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002}" Id="RegKeys" Win64="$(var.win64Flag)">
           <RegistryKey ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes" Id="Acme" Key="SOFTWARE\Acme\[ProductName]" Root="HKLM" />
           <RegistryValue Id="Version" Key="SOFTWARE\Acme\[ProductName]"  Name="Version" Root="HKLM" Type="string" Value="[ProductVersion]" />
       </Component>
       <Component Guid="{0ae4440c-c8d1-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002}" Id="setupdll" SharedDllRefCount="yes" Win64="$(var.win64Flag)">
            <File DiskId="1" Id="f_acme_s" Name="acmeodbcs.dll" Source="acmeodbcs.dll" />
       </Component>
       <Component Guid="{12cd6c2a-c8d1-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002}" Id="driver" SharedDllRefCount="yes" Win64="$(var.win64Flag)">
           <File Checksum="yes" DiskId="1" Id="f_acmeodbc" Name="acmeodbc.dll" Source="acmeodbc.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
           <ODBCDriver File="f_acmeodbc" Id="Acme_ODBC" Name="Acme ODBC Driver" SetupFile="f_acme_s" />
       </Component>
```

Edit: I found that I couldn't use the ODBCDriver element. When it encountered an existing key it changed the BIN location to the originally installed location, and wouldn't update Driver and Setup values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `ODBCDriver` won't work because it encounters the existing key and changes the bin directory to the originally installed location. Using `RegistryValue` to write the required information overwrites the key/values if they exist, otherwise writes the values.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ODBC in a long time so my answer is untested but 99% should be correct.

The ODBCDriver element ( Windows Installer ODBCDriver table , InstallODBC and RemoveODBC actions)  is a thin abstraction for the underlying registry key/value data.

I'm pretty certain it's going to create/overwrite based on the keyfile of the component.  If your installer reinstalls the component it will reinstall the driver registry entries.    This is influenced by such things as file version of the keyfile.

I need to understand what you mean by you want to retain multiple versions but you also want to update to the latest.  My best interpretation of this would be in each MSI have a versioned driver and a non versioned driver like this:

MyDriver 1.0.msi

MyDriver (latest) 
MyDriver1.0       / main feature

MyDriver 2.0.msi

MyDrier (latest)
MyDriver2.0     /main feature

MyDriver1.0 (optional subfeature)

Comment: Your interpretation is mostly correct. I want to be able to retain 1.0, 1.1, and so on, which I did with changing product code and upgrade code. Patch (or small) updates work with version changes.

What I found after logging was that when using ODBCDriver, if [Acme Driver] already existed under [ODBCINST] it would change the bin directory to the first installed location and overwrite the files there. Getting rid of that and using RegistryValue did the trick.